# Swift change background when button pressed

Tags: ios, swift, button, view, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an app in swift and I want the user to be able to chose the background but there is a problem, all my code is in the GameScene.swift, not the appropriate view controller. How do I make it so that if a button is pressed on a different view controller the background on another view controller changes.

I intend on using the pseudo code:

```
if button pressed:
let background = this skspriteNode
else if this button pressed:
let background = this spriteNode
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the delegation pattern if the controllers have any kind of relation to each other. Alternatively you could post and observe notifications using `UINotificationCenter`